# Doubt regarding Abel Plana summation formula

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, summation-method

I have a doubt regarding the Abel Plana summation formula.

What is the condition to apply the Abel Plana summation formula.??

This question arises because sometimes while evaluating series it gives exact results example given
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\sin k}{k}=\frac{\pi -1}{2}$$
However applying the same formula doesn't gives the correct result for some functions example given :
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} e^{-k^2} \neq \frac{\sqrt{\pi }-1}{2} $$
But this sum indeed is given in terms of Jacobi theta function. However the closed form on right still gives a seemingly nice approximation for the sum.
I guess I'm missing something very silly but any information in simple terms for what function f does the formula can be applied.
Thank you !)

Comment: $|f(z)|$ needs to be bound. From the text book: $\displaystyle |f(z)| \leq \frac{M}{|z|^k}$ where $k>1$ and $M$ are constants independent of $N$. Where the integration region is a square with points $\left(N+\frac1{2}\right)(\pm1 \pm i)$. $e^{-k^2}$ is not bound in this way at $-i$ values.

Comment: Let $k = x+iy$, $k^2 = x^2-y^2 + i2xy$, $e^{-k^2} = e^{y^2-x^2-ixy}$, The $e^{y^2}$ part is not bound in the region independent of $N$.

Comment: @arthur thank you so much for your help it's pretty much clear now !)